# Need assistance with algorithm to find the maximum path in a DAG

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose I had this [Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), where there is a directed edge from each node (other than the nodes in the bottom row) to the two nodes below it:

```
        7
      3   8
    8   1   0
  2   7   4   4
4   5   2   6   5
```

I need to find a path through this DAG where the sum of the nodes' weights is maximized. You can only move diagonally down-left or down-right from a node in this tree. So for example, 7, 3, 8, 7, 5, would give the maximum path in this tree.

The input file contains the DAG formatted in this way

```
7
3 8
8 1 0
2 7 4 4
4 5 2 6 5
```

My question is, what algorithm would be best to find maximum path and also how would this tree be represented in C++?

The node weights are non-negative.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum path"? A traversal from the root to a leaf node that encounters the most intermediate nodes?

Comment: ... the path with the maximum total sum?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen apparently the path through which the numbers add up to the greatest value

Comment: What I meant was greatest weight. 7,3,8,7,5 gives the greatest weight. Ill change it to weight.

Comment: @SethCarnegie The question is confusing because the OP lists a maximum path of "7, 3, 8, 7, 5" which is length 5, but every other path from root to a leaf is the same length

Comment: @HunterMcMillen no, he meant that `7, 3, 8, 7, 5` all add up to a greater number than the sum of the numbers of any other path through the tree

Comment: possible duplicate of [Euler project #18 approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002252/euler-project-18-approach)

Comment: FWIW, this graph is not a tree. A tree node has only one parent. This type of structure is called a direct acyclic graph: direct because every edge has a direction, and acyclic since there is no way to get back to a node.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd represent this triangle with a vector of vectors of `int`s.

Start at the bottom row and compare each adjanced pair of numbers. Take the bigger one and add it to the number above the pair:

```
 5 3             13  3
  \
7 8 6  becomes  7  8  6
^ ^

                  13 3               13 11
                     /
Next iteration   7  8  6   becomes  7  8  6  etc.
                    ^  ^
```

Work your way to the top and when you're done, the tip of the triangle will contain the largest sum.

Comment: This dynamic programming solution is simple and fast. It's how I solved Project Euler #18 and #67.

Comment: Shouldn't it be read '3' instead of '11' in the first intermediate result?

Answer (score 1):

A two-dimensional array would work fine.  You can approach this by using a breadth first traversal, and marking each visited node with the maximum path sum for that node.

For example:

- 7 can only be reached by starting at 7.
- 3 is marked with 10, 8 is marked with 15.
- 8 is marked with 18 (10+8), 1 is marked with 11, then replaced with 16, and 0 is marked with 15.

When the leaf nodes are marked, make a quick run through them to see which is maximal.  Then, you start backtracking by comparing the current node's weight, the weight of the parent nodes, and the edge weight.

Answer (score 0):

**Spoilers**

**If you wanted to solve this problem yourself, don't read the code.**

---

One way you could solve it is to turn the data into a tree (graph actually) and write a recursive algorithm that will find the maximum path through the tree by reducing the tree into smaller subtrees (until you have  a tree with only one node) and start going up from there.

I really like recursive algorithms and working with trees, so I went ahead and wrote a program to do it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    node(int i, node* left = NULL, node* right = NULL) : data(i), left(left), right(right) { }

    node* left, *right;
    int data;
};

/*
      tree:

        7
      3   8
    8   1   0
  2   7   4   4
4   5   2   6   5

*/

std::vector<node*> maxpath(node* tree, int& sum) {
    if (!tree) {
        sum = -1;
        return std::vector<node*>();
    }

    std::vector<node*> path;

    path.push_back(tree);

    if (!tree->left && !tree->right) {
        sum = tree->data;
        return path;
    }

    int leftsum = 0, rightsum = 0;

    auto leftpath = maxpath(tree->left, leftsum);
    auto rightpath = maxpath(tree->right, rightsum);

    if (leftsum != -1 && leftsum > rightsum) {
        sum = leftsum + tree->data;
        copy(begin(leftpath), end(leftpath), back_inserter<vector<node*>>(path));
        return path;
    }

    sum = rightsum + tree->data;
    copy(begin(rightpath), end(rightpath), back_inserter<vector<node*>>(path));
    return path;
}

int main()
{
    // create the binary tree
    // yay for binary trees on the stack
    node b5[] = { node(4), node(5), node(2), node(6), node(5) };
    node b4[] = { node(2, &b5[0], &b5[1]), node(7, &b5[1], &b5[2]), node(4, &b5[2], &b5[3]), node(4, &b5[3], &b5[4]) };
    node b3[] = { node(8, &b4[0], &b4[1]), node(1, &b4[1], &b4[2]), node(0, &b4[2], &b4[3]) };
    node b2[] = { node(3, &b3[0], &b3[1]), node(8, &b3[1], &b3[2]) };

    node n(7, &b2[0], &b2[1]);

    int sum = 0;

    auto mpath = maxpath(&n, sum);

    for (int i = 0; i < mpath.size(); ++i) {
        cout << mpath[i]->data;
        
        if (i != mpath.size() - 1)
            cout << " -> ";
    }

    cout << endl << "path added up to " << sum << endl;
}
```

It printed

> 7 -> 3 -> 8 -> 7 -> 5
>
> path added up to 30

Comment: That solution is waaay too inefficient (exponential complexity versus linear).

Comment: @jpalecek which one is linear? Also it's not too inefficient for me, and there were no efficiency requirements :) The program runs faster than I can blink. I just did it for fun anyways to show another way, and this problem is just for fun too.

Comment: The top voted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9154380/51831) is linear, as well as all the answers on the Project Euler #18 question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002252/euler-project-18-approach). Does it run faster than you can blink on trees of height 30? You may code whatever you want for fun, but this is not something a professional should accept.

Comment: And BTW, with a small twist, your solution would be linear as well. Which is another point AGAINST accepting an exponential solution.

Comment: @jpalecek I haven't tested it on trees of height 30 but I don't need to because this isn't being used on trees of height thirty. Forgive me, but I didn't read where he was a professional and the solution to his problem was going into a commercial product. I think your downvote is really needless. You say "You may code whatever you want for fun", but isn't this whole thing for fun? I think you are taking this way too seriously.

Comment: Seth, the OP didn't say he was 'just doing it for fun', and he didn't say he would be using it on trees of height < 30, it is quite likely that he will be using bigger trees. The OP also asked "what algorithm would be best", and unfortunately an exponential solution would be close to useless in most scenarios, which is why yours is not a good answer to the question given.

Answer (score -3):

the best algorithm would be to

```
open the file,
set a counter to 0.
read each line in the file.
for every line you read,
   increment the counter.
close the file.
that counter is your answer.
```

The best algorithm for representing the tree would be nothing.  As you are not actually doing anything that needs a tree respresentaiton.

Comment: Greatest weight?  that is completely different