# Find maximum sum leaf to root path in a Binary Tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, multidimensional-array, tree

I have created a recursive function to calculate the max path of a binary tree.  I got as feedback that it does not work, but according to me test it provide the correct result. Can someone help me please?

```
private long PathSum(int row, int column, Pyramid pyramid)
{
    // Base case, stop recurse when first row is reached.
    if (row == 0) return pyramid[row, column];

    // Set level to the current cell and add to the end result.
    long value = pyramid[row, column];

    // Continue to the next row.
    if (row != 0)
    {
        // Continue to the next left level.
        long left = pyramid[row - 1, column];

        // Continue to the next right level.
        long right = pyramid[row - 1, column + 1];

        // Get the highest of the left and right.
        long highest = Math.Max(left, right);

        // Get the index of the hightest path.
        int nextColumn = highest == left ? column : column + 1;

        // Recurse to the next level and add results together.
        value += GetTotal(row – 1, nextColumn, pyramid);
    }
    // Return result to the caller.
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Ask the feedback, what they expected, what they got, and try to debug then. Also this looks suspicious for c `Math.Max(left, right)`.

Comment: This does not look like C code - more like Java or C#. What language is this? What's a `Pyramid`?

Comment: I asked but they cannot tell me more.  As I said, I tested it and for me works it fine.

Comment: I am sorry, it is C#, I am also developing using C. :-(

Comment: I moved to C#, It is a pyramid.

Comment: It seems your test is not complete, make more test cases and get more feedback. Maybe you are missing pyramid[row - 1, column - 1];

Comment: This looks messed up, what is max path? I don't think your algorithms does what you think it does. Also I like ternary expressions but this looks kinda like black magic `int nextColumn = highest == left ? column : column + 1;`. Also since, you can only give examples of it working, Ima say it works, tell the testers they are just messing with you =)

Comment: @luk32, Can you please give me an hint?

Comment: I think the question is quite clear, I have a method that should return the max path of a pyramid.  If someone cannot get it does not mean that the code are off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a critical mistake in your algorithm: you only walk through the 'pyramid' once and select the based case based on the next result, without looking at underlying nodes.
To illustrate what you are doing, consider the following pyramid:

```
     1
   2   3
311  6    3
```

Assuming that you start at 1, the following will be executed:

1. Look at the max out of the underlying nodes (2 and 3).
2. Go down to the next node (3) and repeat.

Your algorithm will return 10 (1 + 3 + 6) while the maximum value in my example is 311 + 2 + 1, because it doesn't look ahead.

You require a strategy to look further than one step ahead in order to determine the best path.

Edit: look at [Euler project #18 approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002252/euler-project-18-approach) for more hints.

Comment: Thank you Bas, I have just solved the 2nd of Euler Project.  So, I have to go to see the 18th.

Comment: Hi Bas, Can you please tell me which is the wrong part? isidorouk@yahoo.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing is not a binary tree but a pyramid of numbers, and the problem is best solved using dynamic programming instead of tree traversal. Here is a sample code for dynamic programming. It is not compiled and I don't know C# by the way:

```
private long DP(int maxRow, Pyramid pyramid) 
{
    int maxColumn = maxRow;
    Pyramid result; 
    clear_pyramid(result); 
    for (int j=0; i<maxColumn; i++) {
        result[0, j] = pyramid[0, j];
    }    
    for (int i=1; i<maxRow; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<maxColumn-i; j++) {
            result[i,j] = Math.max(result[i-1,j], result[i-1,j+1]) + pyramid[i,j];
        }    
    }
    return result[maxRow-1, 0];
}
```

Comment: a pyramid is in fact a type of binary tree.

Comment: Oh why, I guess the pyramid you mention has 2^n numbers at level n? If we are talking about pyramid with n+1 numbers at level n, then I think it is not a tree. For example we have 1 at level 0, 2 3 at level 1, 4 5 6 at level 2, then both 2 and 3 are connected to both 1 and 5, which means there are two paths between them, and this contradicts with the definition of tree.

Comment: @justinzhang A tree is simply a graph that has no cycles.  The fact that a node is the child of two different nodes does not mean that it is not a tree.  For it to not be a tree a node would have to have one of its ancestors (or itself) as its child, thus creating a cycle.