# project euler brute force choosing each path

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to brute force the following problem 
https://projecteuler.net/problem=18

I can't think of a solution and my head is stucked, I don't know how to choose each path. what I did is the following

```
vector<vector<int> > triangle =
    {
        { 3 },
        { 7, 4 },
        { 2, 4, 6 },
        { 8, 5, 9, 3 }
    };

    int maxSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < triangle.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < triangle[i].size(); j++)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: This would be the "challenge" part of a coding challenge website. If you want to spoil that challenge, you can certainly drop "euler problem 18" in any web search box [including this very site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002252/euler-project-18-approach) and reap the results, but SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Do I have to make 4 loops to scan each path ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I dont want to code the dynamic programming solution, I need the brute force approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   3
  7 4
 2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

When brute-forcing, you have to sum the numbers of following branches and find the maximum:

- 3, 7, 2, 8
- 3, 7, 2, 5
- 3, 7, 4, 5
- ...
- 3, 4, 6, 3

How do you generate such sequences?

Comment: based on the depth of the triangle, I should I make 4 loops ?

Comment: @AndreAhmed: this problem is easier to solve if you use recursion, instead of loops. However yes, you can use 4 loops (in this particular case, not in the general case).

Comment: should I convert the triangle to a tree, and do depth first search in the tree ?