# using recursion for solving Euler 18 in q

Tags: kdb

I have written this code in q for solving Euler 18 problem,as described in the link below, using recursion.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002252/euler-project-18-approach
```

Though the code works, it is not efficient and gets stack overflow at pyramids of sizes greater than 3000. How could I make this code much more efficient.I believe the optimum code can be less than 30 characters.

```
pyr:{[x]
    lsize:count x;
    y:x;
    $[lsize <=1;y[0];
    [.ds.lastone:x[lsize - 1];
    .ds.lasttwo:x[lsize - 2];
    y:{{max (.ds.lasttwo)[x] +/: .ds.lastone[x],.ds.lastone[x+1]}each til count .ds.lasttwo};
    $[(count .ds.lasttwo)=1;y:{max (.ds.lasttwo) +/: .ds.lastone[x],.ds.lastone[x+1]}0;y:y[]];
    x[lsize - 2]:y;
    pyr[-1_x]]]
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly implement this logic in q you need to use adverbs.

First, to quickly find the rolling maximums you can use the [`prior`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#prior) adverb. For example:

```
q)input:(75;95 64;17 47 82;18 35 87 10;20 04 82 47 65;19 01 23 75 03 34;88 02 77 73 07 63 67;99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92;41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33;41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29;53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14;70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57;91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48;63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31;04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23)
q)last input
4 62 98 27 23 9 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 4 23
q)1_(|) prior last input
62 98 98 27 23 70 98 98 93 93 53 60 60 23
```

That last line outputs the a vector with the maximum value between each successive pair in the input vector. Once you have this you can add it to the next row and repeat.

```
q)foo:{y+1_(|) prior x}
q)foo[input 14;input 13]
125 164 102 95 112 123 165 128 166 109 122 147 100 54
```

Then, to apply this function over the whole use the [`over`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#over) adverb:

```
q)foo over reverse input
,1074
```

EDIT: The approach above can be generalized further.

q provides a moving max function [`mmax`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/stats-moving/#mmax). With this you can find "the `x`-item moving maximum of numeric y", which generalizes the use of `prior` above. For example, you can use this to find the moving maximum of pairs or *triplets* in the last row of the input:

```
q)last input
4 62 98 27 23 9 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 4 23
q)2 mmax last input
4 62 98 98 27 23 70 98 98 93 93 53 60 60 23
q)3 mmax last input
4 62 98 98 98 27 70 98 98 98 93 93 60 60 60
```

`mmax` can be used to simplify `foo` above:

```
q)foo:{y+1_ 2 mmax x}
```

What's especially nice about this is that it can be used to generalize to variants of this problem with wider triangles. For example, the triangle below has two more values on each row and from any point on a row you can move to the left, middle, or right of the row below it.

```
    5
  5 6 7
6 7 3 9 1
```

Comment: Where is the value for 'y' is set or comes from? Is this converge iterator or recursion in q?

Comment: `y` is an [implicit parameter](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#617-implicit-parameters), just like `x`. In the example above `x` is `input 14` and `y` is `input 13`. 

This operation is best described as [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). This [documentation](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#over) from Kx describes the behavior in more detail.