# Maximum Summary Path in a Pyramid with non Prime Check

Tags: java, math

I need to find maximum summary path in a pyramid with non prime number check. I wrote the code below to find it. I have found 8219 as an answer. But it is wrong. My problem completion steps are:

1. Read file line by line into a two-dimensional array.
2. Find file's line number to use it later for n*(n+1)/2 formula. (It is a formula for triangular numbers so you cand find how many numbers this pyramid contains.
3. Check all indexes of two-dimensional array to zeroing all prime numbers.
4. Start from down to top to find the maximum summary path step by step.

My input pyramid: https://hastebin.com/epugidefix

Also problem rules are:

1. You will start from the top and move downwards to an adjacent number as in below.
2. You are only allowed to walk downwards and diagonally.
3. You can only walk over NON PRIME NUMBERS.
4. You have to reach at the end of the pyramid as much as possible.
5. You have to treat your input as pyramid.

   ```
    //Function that checks given number is prime or not. Returns true if it is prime.
    static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        //check if n is a multiple of 2
        if (n%2==0) return false;
        //if not, then just check the odds
        for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //Function that finds path which goes to maximum summary path.
    static int maxPathSum(int tri[][], int m) 
    { 
        m= m-1;
        // loop for bottom-up calculation 
        for (int i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
            { 
                // for each element, check both 
                // elements just below the number 
                // and below right to the number 
                // add the maximum of them to it 
                if (tri[i + 1][j] > tri[i + 1][j + 1]){
                    tri[i][j] += tri[i + 1][j];
                }
                else{
                    tri[i][j] += tri[i + 1][j + 1];
                }
            }
        } 

        // return the top element 
        // which stores the maximum sum 
        return tri[0][0];
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int lineNumber = 0; //Variable to hold File's total line number.

        //Getting total line number of file.
        try{
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
          while (reader.readLine() != null) lineNumber++;
          reader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex1){
          System.out.println("File not Found");    
        }

        int[][] pyram = new int[lineNumber][lineNumber];    //Array holding the pyramid.

        //Getting inputs from file.
        try{
          File file = new File("input.txt");
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
          int count = 0;
          int currentLine = 0;
          while(currentLine != lineNumber)
          {
           if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                if(count+1==lineNumber){
                    currentLine++;
                    count=0;
                }
                else{ 
                    if(count > currentLine){
                        pyram[currentLine][count] = 0;
                        count++;
                    }
                    else{
                        pyram[currentLine][count] = scanner.nextInt();
                        count++;
                    }
                }
           }else{
               break;
           }
          }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
          System.out.println("File not Found");
        }

        //Loop for zeroing all prime numbers in pyramid.
        for(int i=1; i<lineNumber; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<lineNumber; j++){
                int temp= pyram[i][j];
                if(isPrime(temp) == true){
                    pyram[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<lineNumber; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<lineNumber; j++){
                System.out.print(pyram[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //Printing maximum summary to screen.
        System.out.println(maxPathSum(pyram,lineNumber));
    }
   ```

Comment: It is still a problem. I don't know what my problem is..

Comment: Problem rules 1. "You will start from the TOP and move DOWN to an adjacent number". But you also mentioned that "loop for BOTTOM-UP calculation" which is indeed bottom-up calculation. Those two approaches will result differently

Comment: Thanks for replying but i tried top-down calculation,too. And it returns the same result that i mentioned above = 8219. Also i don't agree with you. Because it is the maximum summary path algorithm so it is not important what is your choice top-bottom or bottom-top. They need to return same number as an answer.

Comment: Check out problem rules 3 and 4, then imagine that there is one whole level on your pyramid with only prime numbers, it is like a dead end. In this case your max path from bottom will be different than max path from top. Also your approach matters in this problem too. Now you have greedy approach which is fine and efficient for bottom-top. But for top-bottom there is no guarantee that greedy can find the max path, you need to use frontier approach. You can see the difference between them [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002252/euler-project-18-approach) So direction matters in here

Comment: thanks so much for your answer.