# Find the possible slide downs in a pyramid

Tags: python, recursion

I'm losing my mind with this codewars/project euler problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/551f23362ff852e2ab000037/train/python

I need to find the max sum in all of the possible pyramid slide downs, and as of right know I'm trying to calculate the possible slide downs that exist in the pyramid. It works fine but for integers bigger than 25 the function begins to be really slow.

My code is this:

```
def find_seq(x):
'''
input: x, positive integer greater than 1

Returns an array with the slides from the top to the bottom of
an x floors high pyramid
'''
list_slides = []
if x == 2:
    return [[0,0],[0,1]]
else:
    prev_slides = find_seq(x-1)
    for el in prev_slides:
        list_slides.append([0]+el)
    for el in prev_slides:
        list_slides.append([0]+list(i+1 for i in el))
return list_slides
```

I can see that for each new floor the calculating time grows exponentially but I can't think of any other way to adress the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend looking into [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). The problem is equivalent to [PE #18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18) so you might look for tips on that.

Comment: I know I need to apply memoization in the next step but if you mean to do it now I don't know how tbh

Comment: It's easy to hand the solution to you if you want it and a quick web or SO search will turn up thousands of solutions to this problem, but I think researching memoization yourself and walking through tutorials on Fibonacci numbers, then trying to apply it to your problem would be more educational/satisfying. The idea is to create a lookup hash--if you've called the function before with specific parameters then you just return the solution for that call instead of doing the work all over again from scratch. Overlapping subproblems. It's a one-liner in Python using the functools module.

Comment: Nah, I don't want the solution tbh. I've searched about memoization but I don't see where I'm repeating the call to the function. If i do find_seq(8), i need to calculate once find_seq(7), for which i need to calculate find_seq(6) and so on; but I calculate them only once. I don't know if there is another way to calculate the slide downs...

Comment: If you're talking about the example in the linked CW kata description, what you say is true for edge elements but you can see that the middle `4` is reachable from either `7` or `4` in the row above it. That means when you apply your function to the middle element, it's going to do the exact same work and return the same value back to each of its parents of its best path to the bottom of the triangle multiple times. If you're not sure, print the arguments in your function calls and you'll see you have overlap that blows up complexity as you add more rows.

Comment: Also, the header they give you provides the entire pyramid but your recursive calls will probably be better defined as "find the best path from cell row, col" starting at the top. So I'd write an inner function `find_best_path(pyramid, row, col)` that saves copying the pyramid every time, and you can memoize on the basis of "have I already computed the best path for this row, col pair within the pyramid?".

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Go from the bottom up for linear complexity.

Well, you are right it grows exponentially.
The problem is not your code, but your **direction**.
Let's look at the pyramid from bottom up - you can see right away that if you are at the second to last layer and you want to slide down, you will choose the path that is directly under you and has the larger value, i.e  you can slide only left or right and the bigger will be better.
Now, going up to the third to last, you only need to find the route down to the floor below which is the best (summing up the value of the bottom floor of course).
keep going like that to the top of the pyramid and by the end, you get the value of the best route, or longest slide.

code:

```py
def longest_slide_down(pyramid):
    if len(pyramid) == 1:
        return pyramid[0][0]

    last_layer = pyramid[-1]
    add_layer = []
    for i in range(1, len(last_layer)):
        add_layer.append(max(last_layer[i], last_layer[i-1]))
    
    pyramid[-2] = [a+b for a, b in zip(pyramid[-2], add_layer)]
    
    return longest_slide_down(pyramid[:-1])
```

And for the efficiency seekers out there, a numpyed version of the same code:

```py
import numpy as np
def longest_slide_down(pyramid):
    if len(pyramid) == 1:
        return pyramid[0][0]
    
    pyramid = np.array(pyramid)
    pyramid[-2] += np.maximum(pyramid[-1][:-1], pyramid[-1][1:])
    return longest_slide_down(pyramid[:-1])
```

Comment: Another answer which explains bottom up approach that may be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002252/euler-project-18-approach - @mishadoff explanation